# Magento 2.3.4 - Order page return 500 error

Tags: magento2.3.4, http-error-500

If click place order button getting 5005 error,

[image]

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Zend\Log\Logger::error() in /usr/share/nginx/html/giri/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender.php:88**

Log Error :

main.INFO: Broken reference

shipping.log :

```
<Response>
<ServiceHeader>
<MessageTime>2020-07-19T13:12:03.616+02:00</MessageTime>
</ServiceHeader>
<Status>
<ActionStatus>Error</ActionStatus>
<Condition>
<ConditionCode>111</ConditionCode>
<ConditionData>Error in parsing request XML:An invalid
XML character (Unicode: 0x1f) was found in the
element content of the document.</ConditionData>
</Condition>
</Status>
</Response></res:ErrorResponse>
```

Comment: check your exception log

Comment: @AfreenSheikh There is no exception.log under var/log instead of system.log => https://codeshare.io/axJdRX  & debug.log =>https://codeshare.io/5R4r14

Comment: Click on error in console and check response in network.It seems issue with payment method.

Comment: @Pawan Network error empty https://snipboard.io/Oygcu6.jpg

Comment: I did not ask network tab. go to network tab, click `Preserve log`, click on place order and then check response for request you are getting 500

Comment: shipping.log error https://justpaste.it/2uywx

Comment: @Pawan Pls check with my updated post

Comment: it seems there is space in your layout (xml) file. did you recently change/edit any XML ?

Comment: Are u using DHL Shipping ?

Comment: @Pawan No, not using DHL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110783/discussion-between-zus-and-pawan).